# How to set default date in text box? Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i am using jquery 1.10

**view Template**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#departing_on" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
      numberOfMonths:[1,2],
      minDate: new Date() 
    });
    $( "#return_on" ).datepicker({ 
      dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
      numberOfMonths:[1,2],
      minDate: new Date() 
    });
    });
</script>
```

First time while selecting I want default today's date in text box. how ?

Comment: you got it `setDate: new Date()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#departing_on").val($.datepicker.formatDate("dd-mm-yy", new Date()));
$("#return_on").val($.datepicker.formatDate("dd-mm-yy", new Date()));
```

Add the above code at the end of the script. This is required because the datepicker plugin has no provision to set the date in the control while initializing.

Comment: Oh! sorry its correct only, i have just given in new script tag that's why its not working. Thanks for response...

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure of what you are asking. You can get current date in JavaScript:

```
var now = new Date();
```

If you want to go to current date in jQuery DatePicker, you can apply it on any textfield like this:

```
$('input.youTextFieldClass').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy', 
                                     changeMonth: true,
                                     changeYear: true,
                                     yearRange: '-70:+10',
                                     constrainInput: false,
                                     duration: '',
                                     gotoCurrent: true});
```

Comment: var now = new Date(); #Tue Dec 17 2013 18:17:47 GMT+0530 (IST) i want in 17-12-2013 format.

Comment: First time while selecting the date I want to show default today's date in text box. that's it

Answer (score 1):

just put in the the input field ;)

```
<input type="text" id="departing_on" value="23-03-2013" />
```

Comment: haha that's correct, that's just a random date ;) but you can insert any date you'd like, in example the birth date of Napoleon Bonaparte :p

Comment: Tell me your birth date i will put there

Comment: http://stevenlevithan.com/assets/misc/date.format.js. Use the script to format the date and use .text() to set it.

Comment: I mean, use .val() to set the text.

Comment: @Vishal, Here i am using 'dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"' then why we need again date format.

Comment: Sorry my bad.. you dont have to use date.format.js. You can use the existing $.datepicker.formatDate to get the job done. Please find the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is :

```
<input type="text" id="departing_on" class="datepicker form-control input-sm" value='' />

<script type="text/javascript">
function getCurrentDate(){
  today_date = new Date();

  today_Date_Str = ((today_date.getDate() < 10) ? "0" : "") + String(today_date.getDate()) + "-" +((today_date.getMonth() < 9) ? "0" : "") + String(today_date.getMonth() + 1)+ "-" +today_date.getFullYear();

  return today_Date_Str;
}
</script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#departing_on").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
      numberOfMonths:[1,2],
      minDate: new Date(),
      // gotoCurrent: true
    });
    $("#return_on").datepicker({ 
      dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
      numberOfMonths:[1,2],
      minDate: new Date() 
    });
  });
$(function() {
     var date = new Date(); // replace with your date
     $("#departing_on").val(getCurrentDate());
});
</script>
```