# Can Datepicker Automatically Fill in the Date Textbox After Page Loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to get today date from jquery datepicker and insert it to text field when page is loaded. How should I do it?

Comment: Please Refer the answers....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233553/how-do-i-pre-populate-a-jquery-datepicker-textbox-with-todays-date

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633982/how-to-set-default-date-in-text-box-jquery

Comment: @Revathi Muthukrishnan But it gives incorrect date. Why is that?